# jpa - delete OneToMany violates foreign key constraint

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, one-to-many

I have two mapped entities, `AssignmentOpsEntity` and `ConventionalOptionEntity`. I want to remove an `AssignmentOpsEntity` with all `conventionalOption`. So i removed all conventionalOption from `AssignmentOpsEntity`, then i deleted the conventionalOption from database, finally i removed the object `AssignmentOpsEntity`. But i have the below error.

> ERROR: update or delete on table "assignmentopsentity" violates
> foreign key constraint "fkll31qdog9ye067ybhltjey6u7" on table
> "conventionaloptionentity"   Détail : Key
> (assignmentopsid)=(8bf4a6b3-c09e-4da1-a88d-d49d9f7b63f6) is still
> referenced from table "conventionaloptionentity".

```
@Entity
public class AssignmentOpsEntity {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "assignmentOps", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<ConventionalOptionEntity> conventionalOption;

  public void removeConventionalOption(Set<ConventionalOptionEntity> conventionalOption) {
    this.conventionalOption.removeAll(conventionalOption);
    conventionalOption.forEach(item -> item.assignmentOps(null));
  }

}

@Entity
public class ConventionalOptionEntity {
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private AssignmentOpsEntity assignmentOps;
    
}

public void on(OpsDetachedFromAgreementEvent event) {
    Optional<AssignmentOpsEntity> assignmentOpsEntityOptional = assignmentOpsRepository.findById(event.assignmentOpsId);
    if (assignmentOpsEntityOptional.isPresent()) {
        AssignmentOpsEntity assignmentOpsEntity = assignmentOpsEntityOptional.get();
        assignmentOpsEntity.removeConventionalOption(assignmentOpsEntity.getConventionalOption());
        conventionalOptionRepository.deleteAll(assignmentOpsEntity.getConventionalOption());
        assignmentOpsRepository.delete(assignmentOpsEntity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "assignmentOps", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<ConventionalOptionEntity> conventionalOption;
```

`CascadeType.ALL` means here that `conventionalOption` entities are deleted when you delete a parent entity

So here the code you need

```
public void on(OpsDetachedFromAgreementEvent event) {
    Optional<AssignmentOpsEntity> assignmentOpsEntityOptional = assignmentOpsRepository.findById(event.assignmentOpsId);
    if (assignmentOpsEntityOptional.isPresent()) {
        assignmentOpsRepository.delete(assignmentOpsEntity);
    }
}
```